# Angular + Firebase - Authentication error / Database Rules issue

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Angular2 and Firebase. And this is the first time I've tried authentication.  After setting the Firebase database Rules to:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

i get this error in the browser and I don't get any data loading:
[image]

The error is gone and data loads OK if the database is totally open like this (but i understand this is not good!):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write;
     }
   }
 }
```

Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong here please?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of sign-in method did you enable in the **Authentication** section of the Firebase Console?

You have to enable at least one of them to make your rule works.

Here is the documentation: [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password)

EDIT:

After **swisstony** comment.

You can follow this link, it explains how email and password authentication works.

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password

First you have to create an account with an email and a password.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
});
```

And then you can log in

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
});
```

Comment: Hi Turbo. I had enabled Email/Password.